# How to switch between desktops without previewing the animation image

Tags: 21.10, workspace-switcher, animations

I have a problem while switching workspaces on ubuntu, and the problem is that I can't disable this animation image that keeps showing up when I use the keyboard shortcut ctrl + alt + (left/right)key.
When I'm using a notebook with smark touchpad, I can use the touch with 3 fingers to make this animation image doesn't apper, so I can visualize the content from the new desktop faster than when doing this using the keybord.
So I would like to ask, if there is any way I can disable this.

[image of the animation I'm speaking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFggB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the extension [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) who provides many tweaks to Gnome including remove workspace switch pop-up.

Comment: Nice!! This works for me!! Thank you